# Are Borel-measurable functions limits of sequences of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

One definiton of Borel measurable functions is:

> The collection of borel measurable functions is the smallest
>   collection of real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that contains the
>   continuous functions and is closed under pointwise limits.

Now my question. **Is every Borel measureable function then according to this definition the pointwise limit of continuous functions?**

What can go wrong is this: $\{f_n^k\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\rightarrow f^k$, and we assume that all $f_n^k$ are continuous. $f^k$ need not be continuous. And lets say that $\{f^k\}\rightarrow f$, now since the borel measurable functions is closed under pointwise limits, f has to be borel-measurable. But we haven't shown that it is a limit of continuous functions. Can such an f exist that is not a limit of continuous functions?

I tried proving that indeed f was a limit of continuous functions, but I couldn't finish my proof, I ran into this problem: [Is this statement about limits true.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052661/is-this-statement-about-limits-true/) I tried proving it with a diagonal-argument, but maybe there is another way to prove what we want?

Is the answer yes and if so, how do I prove it? Or is it not true, and is there a counter-example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tha answer is no.

Every pointwise limit of continuous functions is of Baire class $1$ (this is just the definition), and this implies that the set of discontinuities of $f$ is not all of $\Bbb{R}$ by a Baire category argument (see this post [Construction of a function which is not the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549135/construction-of-a-function-which-is-not-the-pointwise-limit-of-a-sequence-of-con)).

But for example the Borel function $\chi_{\Bbb{Q}}$ (indicator function of the rationals) is discontinuous everywhere, hence not a pointwise limit of continuous functions.